# Why would CSRF errors appear overnight in a Rails app?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, google-chrome, csrf, csrf-protection

I know what CSRF protection is, I know how it works in the context of a Rails app, and I know how to "solve" my problem, e.g., by disabling it.

However, I'd like to keep CSRF protection turned on. My question is, what would cause the error:

`Can't verify CSRF token authenticity`

To appear overnight? Nothing has been pushed to production (i.e., not a code issue, and FYI I'm not using Devise). Still using the same browser (Chrome on desktop) which has not been updated. Using the same form (a template that every user uses). Literally yesterday it was all working fine, and today it suddenly isn't.

Comment: Ever heard of debugging?

Answer (score 0):

Only guessing possible here I guess.

- Precondition: There is no bug ;-)  Guess: A real CSRF attack is going on.
- Precondition: Not yet checked twice. Guess: Something had been modified on production. Maybe it was not even pushed, but directly changed.
- Precondition: Production site is not heavily used. Guess: It was broken since longer than the night before. Nobody noticed, since all they did was logging in and triggering some 'GET' requests, and not the template form.
- "csrf-token" or "csrf_token"? Sometimes GET and POST requests modify the variable name. Especially if you disable Javascript and the original post becomes a get. Of course that would be a different route, but still might throw the csrf error.